# Adding a Static Cell before Dynamic Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to have one cell that will some static text with some labels on it, but since i am using dynamic cells, it populates every cell with whatever data is inside the NSArray(s).

This is my source code where i am "styling" my dynamic cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandingsIdent";
    StandingsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    long row = [indexPath row];
    cell.cellTeamName.text = _teamNames[row];
    cell.cellTeamLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_teamLogos[row]]; 
    cell.cellTeamPosition.text = _teamPosition[row]; 

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:235.0/255.0 green:235.0/255.0 blue:235.0/255.0 alpha:1];  } 
    else { 
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Anyone willing to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like that and configure first cell to your liking:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
// Configure static cell differently
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: But that's like just cheating, you pretty much are populating labels for index0 and not for the rest, this is not a solution more like a workaround.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a code to do custom population for all cells except for the first one. Why adding similar logic for the first one is cheating?

Comment: For the else (the other dynamic cells), I think that he should decrement the `indexPath.row` by 1 (minus 1), because the first `indexPath.row`(which is equals 0) is assigned to the first static cell.

Comment: this is kind of obvious. cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called for all cells and you need to accomodate for shift if your datasource is shorter.